# how to pass URL path params to navitems in coreUI/angular sidebar

Tags: angular, core-ui

I am using coreui/angular@2.9.1 in one of my projects. I have a requirement to pass URL path params to the navitems.

Below is my current code and it is appending the encoded URL:

`navItems = {name: 'page 1', url: '/page/view;test=abc;pass=xyz'}`

Current output: `localhost:4200/#/page/view%3Btest%3Dabc%3Bpass%3Dxyz`

Expected Output: `localhost:4200/#/page/view;test=abc;pass=xyz`

Let me know if any further information is needed on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with below code:

navItems = {name: 'page 1', url: ['/page', 'view', { 'test': 'abc', 'pass': 'xyz' } ] };

Thanks to coreUI support team.